# Is there a way for extreme points of a convex set to get as close to each other as possible?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

This question relates to linear programming problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the constraints y≥-x, y≥x and y≥ε and make ε as small as you want.

Comment: @Issledovatelnitsa: well, there is nothing really clever. Take two points as close as you want, and let three lines go through them.

Comment: @Issledovatelnitsa: in a Ukranian pub ?